# What is the proper way to handle component's state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I've seen people use the `setState` way:

`this.setState( {enteredlocation: newLocation});`

Currently I'm writing to the state like this:

`this.state.id.push({"no" : length , "location": this.state.enteredlocation});`

What is the proper way to update the state?

I'm also going to integrate Redux later on but for now, I'm trying to understand part by part.

Comment: The proper way is to use `this.setState` and **NEVER** mutate the `this.state` object directly. Btw, I'm sure `this.state.id.push()` does not trigger the component re-rendering, so it's not obvious how that call is useful at all.

Comment: Yes, it does not re-render when using `this.state.id.push()` which makes me confused why. Is there an explanation to this? I guess I'll use `this.setState`

Comment: "Is there an explanation to this?" --- sure: react is not aware of the change you've just made.

Comment: so basically, you mean react can only be aware of the changes when we only use `this.setState`? Are there other ways to return a new state normally?

Comment: You don't "return" it - you "set" it. `this.setState` - sets the new state of the component.

Comment: I see, alright thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
this.state.id.push({"no" : length , "location": this.state.enteredlocation});
```

...do:

```
this.setState({ 
  id: this.state.id.concat({
    "no": length, 
    "location": this.state.enteredlocation
  })
});
```

This will ensure that `id` is a new array reference, not the same reference with different contents.

Comment: I've seen people using `Object.assign()` to combine new objects. What is the difference of it when using `concat`?

Comment: `concat` is easier for Arrays; Object.assign is a good way to update an object. Or use spread (even easier): `{ ...this.state.origObj, newProp: 'value' }`